# Use of Item in coverpoint

Tags: system-verilog

In the below code, can someone please explain what "item" refers to?

```
covergroup cg(bit ip);
 coverpoint txn_type {
    bins T0 = {0};
    bins T1 = {1};
    bins T2 = {2} with (((item || (!item)) && ip) == 1);
  }
endgroup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always start with the IEEE Std, 1800-2017.  Refer to section 19.5.1.1 *Coverpoint bin with covergroup expressions*:

> The **with** clause specifies that only those values in the
> *covergroup_range_list* that satisfy the given expression (i.e., for
> which the expression evaluates to true, as described in 12.4) are
> included in the bin. In the expression, the name **item** shall be used to
> represent the candidate value. The candidate value is of the same type
> as the coverpoint.

Think of `item` as an implicitly-declared variable used in the `with` construct.  In your code, `item` represents the coverpoint variable, `txn_type`.

Answer (score 0):

"item" should refer to the "covergroup_range_list" or "coverpoint variable".
Your code maybe is wrong.